# Search not working inside Document library in SharePoint online site collection

Tags: sharepoint-online, 2013, search, 2016

I have a site collection in SharePoint online.

When I goto the library that is in modern view, I see "Search this library" search bar on top.

But when I enter name of the document that is existing, it is not bringing any relevant results

I get the same result that says

> We couldn't find any results for **pdf**

for any query that I search for.

I tried reindexing the site collection from Site Settings, but it didn't work either.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I have seen something similar in the past, I think this happened, in that case, when someone tried searching before the page had completely loaded. I believe even selecting inside the search bar would cause the problem as well. Is the page/library fully loaded before entering and searching? If not, could you see if that makes a difference?

Answer (score 1):

Check as follows:

1. Make sure that **Allow items from this document library to appear in
   search results?** is set to Yes.
2. Verify that the version of the document that's missing from search
   results is a major version of the document. If the version is a
   minor version, it will not be displayed in the search results until
   it's checked in and published as a major version.
3. Please also check whether others files can be search, such as word documents.

More information:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/troubleshoot/search/search-results-missing

Answer (score 0):

By default, you just need to WAIT for some HOURS or DAYS for proper re-indexing. This usually happen when you just added the user to the list or document library.